# Computer Cables two different awg connected together

Tags: sata, cable

I have a 22awg sata power cable. I am looking to split it with something like this ([https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Latching-Power-Splitter-Adapter/dp/B00BBDL17G/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BBDL17G)) that is 18awg. Should I have any concerns with the different wire gauges?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The smaller the awg the thicker the cable the more amps it can handle. House wiring is 14 for 15amps and 12 for 20A for comparison.

Most hard drives use 1-2A max on the 12V and <2A on the 5V.  Two drives together shouldn't be an issue.

Now if you tried to do additional daisy chaining you might.

If the wires get hot you have a problem.

http://www.offroaders.com/technical/12-volt-wiring-tech-gauge-to-amps/

Indicates 18 gauge is fine up to 3 feet for 30A.  Your cable is much shorter so that should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I was just concerned if there were any issues with using two different cables of different awg connected together. Wasn't sure if the connection point between the two would run into any issues with heat or anything.